# Connected Arduino via Bluetooth doesn't show up in in COM ports nor can be added

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I was trying to communicate with my Arduino (Nano BLE) using serial ports, because using `Bleak` library didn't work as expected. However, when I tried to find the device in device manager under COM ports, I couldn't. I am able to connect the Arduino to my device via Bluetooth; at least it seems so:

[image]

[image]

I tried to manually add a port but it the Arduino doesn't appear. The code in my Arduino is:

```cpp
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

BLEService ledService("07694453-2dd6-4a4c-8c1e-1e3466a6c5734");
BLECharCharacteristic switchChar("2cf11b06-ce75-4d8e-ad1a-be116a432fa2", BLEWrite | BLERead);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  // while (!Serial);

  if (!BLE.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Failed to initialize BLE.");
    while (1);
  }

  BLE.setLocalName("Arduino Nano BLE");
  BLE.setAdvertisedService(ledService);
  ledService.addCharacteristic(switchChar);
  BLE.addService(ledService);

  BLE.advertise();
  Serial.println("BLE Peripheral device started advertising.");
}

void loop() {
  BLEDevice central = BLE.central();

  if (central) {
    Serial.print("Connected to central MAC: ");
    // print the central's BT address:
    Serial.println(central.address());
    // turn on the LED to indicate the connection:
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
   

    while (central.connected()){
      switchChar.writeValue('H');
      delay(1000);
    }
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }
}
```

I suspect that my code is not correct and therefore my connection is not made properly. Do you have any suggestions to make this to work?

Comment: a BLE connection doesn't create a com port. only the Serial Port Profile of classic Bluetooth creates a com port

Comment: @Juraj Oh! I didn't know that. You can write an answer so that I can accept it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a commenter mentioned, BLE connections do not create a COM ports. Bluetooth Low Energy transmits an ID which other devices can find and connect to. Once a device, such as your computer, connects to the BLE device, low-bandwidth (125KB/s-2MB/s) communications commence.
Classic Bluetooth connections, on the other hand, use these (relatively) high-bandwidth (1-3 MB/s) COM ports to send and receive data.

For more information on the difference: https://www.makeuseof.com/what-is-ble-bluetooth-low-energy/

In your case, I would recommend using the `LightBlue` app/application to test your BLE device. It is not the most user-friendly solution (especially if you are intending on making a product for a less tech-inclined end-user), so it may be helpful to look into creating your own app. In this case, I would recommend looking into [Flutter BLE](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_ble/latest/).